# Jenkins schedule: avoid job execution on when building scheduled job

Tags: jenkins, schedule

I scheduled a job in Jenkins to run each day at 1800 stopping some process. After I made configuration in Jenkins I build the job but it executed immediately and then moved over to the schedule. Can I prevent that first run somehow so let's say I build job at 1400 but it only executes at 1800 and not at 1400 when built?

Comment: So you want it to run at 1800 but only on some days?

Comment: show ur schedule configuration in jenkins

Comment: Jenkins schedule is "0 18 * * 1-5". However, if I build the job let's say at 10 it will execute immediately at 10 and does not wait for 18

Comment: oh, i think i got it....build always means "execute now". to not do so i only need to activate and save...